# Utilize HStack to confirm to logo and skip text

Tags: swiftui

Does anyone know how to make the following view in SwiftUI?

HStack:

`[   blank    logo(centered)      Skip(text)]`

So I have the following HStack:
[image]

```
Zstack(alignment: .topLeading) {
  VStack{
    HStack {
        Image("onboarding-logo")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 150.0, height: 150.0)
            .padding(.top, 35)
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can have a "Skip" text in the top right corner of the screen, but also keep my logo centered and not have anything on the left side? I've tried Spacers and all, but I'm having no luck.

I would like to click "Skip" and then lead to another view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There are many ways to achieve this.* Here I have used `LazyVGrid` since other answers based on `Stack`s

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem()], content: {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                    .border(.gray)
                Button(action: {
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("Skip")
                })
            })
            .border(.gray)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is this the screen configuration you want?
The `Zstack` is used to center the Hstack into which the image is placed, and the new HStack uses a spacer to move the Text to the right.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Image("farnsworth")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 150.0, height: 150.0)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        // do Something...
                    } label: {
                        Text("Skip>>")
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```